# template overload for tuple-like types (tuple, pair)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am trying to provide two versions of the same templated function, one for anything that can act like a `tuple`, that is, something that works with `tuple_size` and `std::get`.  I don't care if it gets `std::array`s, as long as it gets tuple and pair.  It's no problem to write the general version, but I can't seem to get the tuple-like version to stick.

```
// 1
template <typename T>
A func(T&& t) { /* ... */ }

// 2
template <typename TupleType,
          std::size_t Size=std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleType>>::value>
B func(TupleType&& tup) { /* ... */ }
```

with the examples:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    std::vector<int> v;
    auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0, 'a');
    auto p = std::make_tuple(1, 2.0);

    A a = func(i); // calls 1
    a = func(v); // calls 1

    B b = func(t); // ambiguous, should call 2
    b = func(p); // ambiguous, should call 2
}
```

I know that I could write a few overloads for tuple, but that's a lot of writing, and would generate an intermediate in the case of `pair`.  I don't want to lose the reference to the original pair since this is just a forwarding function.

```
template <typename... Ts>
B func(std::tuple<Ts...>& tup) { }

template <typename... Ts>
B func(const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup) { }

template <typename... Ts>
B func(std::tuple<Ts...>&& tup) { }
```

Is there anyway I can make the above calls in `main` work the way I want, with one generic forwarding function?

**Update**: the return types of these functions differ.  should have included that first, I oversimplified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct is_tuple_like : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_tuple_like<T, decltype((void)std::get<0>(std::declval<T>()), (void)std::tuple_size<T>::value)> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_tuple_like<std::decay_t<T>>{}, int> = 0>
A func(T&& t)
{
    return {};
}

template <typename TupleType, std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_like<std::decay_t<TupleType>>{}, int> = 0>
B func(TupleType&& tup)
{
    return {};
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c558fe9a5499750)

---

An alternative solution with a tag dispatching:

```
template <typename T>
A _func(T&& t, std::false_type)
{
    return {};
}

template <typename TupleType>
B _func(TupleType&& tup, std::true_type)
{
    return {};
}

template <typename TupleOrNot>
auto func(TupleOrNot&& t)
{
    return _func(std::forward<TupleOrNot>(t), is_tuple_like<std::decay_t<TupleOrNot>>{});
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35ecf2772c374509)

Comment: +1, but tag dispatching would be cleaner than SFINAE.

Answer (score 2):

Make the second function template one a better match if it works:

```
// 1
template <typename T>
void func_(T&& t, long) { /* ... */ }

// 2
template <typename TupleType,
          std::size_t Size=std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleType>>::value>
void func_(TupleType&& tup, int) { /* ... */ }

template <typename T>
void func(T&& t) { func_(std::forward<T>(t), 0); }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab211c0e091a2669).
The concept can be generalized - [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150128171917/http://flamingdangerzone.com:80/cxx11/2013/03/11/overload-ranking.html) from Xeo explains it quite well.